# WPF4 DataGrid can't display or CancelEdit of an Enum column?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, enums

I've simplified this as much as possible.  I have this `DataGrid` in my window:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="myDataGrid"
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
    GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesDataTable}"
    CellEditEnding="myDataGrid_CellEditEnding"/>
```

My `DataContext` is the class `ViewModel`:

```
enum SomeEnum
{
    Choice1 = 0,
    Choice2
}

class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        var column1 = dataTable.Columns.Add();
        column1.DataType = typeof(string);

        var column2 = dataTable.Columns.Add();
        column2.DataType = typeof(SomeEnum);

        dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Name 1", SomeEnum.Choice1 });
        dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Name 2", SomeEnum.Choice2 });

        this.ValuesDataTable = dataTable;

    }

    public DataTable ValuesDataTable { get; private set; }
}
```

In my window's code-behind, I have this event handler:

```
private void myDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        dataGrid.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

When I run the application column 1 works as expected (it displays the value properly, I can start an edit, and the edit cancels when I try to commit it).  Column 2, however, doesn't display the values.  When you try to edit it, the drop down box with the two Enum choices are displayed, but when you try to commit it, and it executes `CancelEdit`, somewhere in the WPF code it throws an exception and breaks the binding.  The exception is:

```
System.NotSupportedException:
EnumConverter cannot convert from System.Int32
```

I think that the `DataGrid` is reading the value of the Enum column from the `DataTable` as an `int` and it's probably expecting a string.  Is there some way around this?

**Update**

I found that if I handle the `DataGrid.LoadingRow` event, and I get the `ItemData` array, the second column has become an `Int32` instead of the enum.  Attempts to cast it back to the right type aren't helping:

```
private void myDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
    var dataRow = row.Row;
    var itemArray = dataRow.ItemArray;

    // BTW, this doesn't help:
    itemArray[1] = (SomeEnum)itemArray[1];
    dataRow.ItemArray = itemArray;
}
```

Comment: you don't cast an integer to enum like that, did you try enum.parse?

Comment: @Davide Piras - enum.Parse takes a string.  Yes, I tried that and verified itemArray was correct before I set it back.  Also, I'm quite sure you can cast an enum that way, if the object you're casting is an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out why this is happening.  The problem is in the `DataTable`, specifically the `DataRow`, not in the WPF `DataGrid`.

If I change the line in my view model where I add a row to the `DataTable`:

```
var r1 = dataTable.Rows.Add(row1);
```

... and then inspect `r1`, specifically `r1.ItemArray[1]`, it's of type `int`, not `SomeEnum`.  That means it's already lost the type information.

The answer seems to be that I have to use an `ObservableCollection` of some class that I define.  If you have a property type of an enum on that class, it works.